# django models sum of classes fiels

Tags: python, django, class, sum

My Stage is related to Zone via ZoneStage and each Stage has got a value for each Zone.

My SubStage is related to Zone via ZoneSubStage and each SubStage has got a value for each Zone.

Each Stage can have multiple SubStages.

Question: How to display a value for each Stage so the value is a summary the SubStages values related to that Stage ?

e.g.

if Stage 1 has got SubStage 1.1, 1.2, 1.3:

Stage1.value = SubStage1.1.value + SubStage1.2.value + SubStage1.3.value

?

**Here are my models:**

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    zone_name = models.CharField()
    zone_number = models.CharField()


class Stage(models.Model):
    stage_number = models.CharField()
    stage_name = models.CharField()
    zones = models.ManyToManyField(Zone, through='ZoneStage')


class SubStage(models.Model):
    sub_name = models.CharField()
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage)
    zones = models.ManyToManyField(Zone, through='ZoneSubStage')


class ZoneStage(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value =  ZoneSubStage.objects.filter(substage__stage=stage_instance).aggregate(Sum('value'))
        super(ZoneStage, self).save(*args,**kwargs)    


class ZoneSubStage(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
    substage = models.ForeignKey(SubStage)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, you could get the value of a single `Stage` as (with `stage_instance` being your `Stage` instance):

```
ZoneSubStage.objects.filter(substage__stage=stage_instance).aggregate(Sum('value'))
# This will return {'value__sum': 90}
```

If you want to get the value by calling `stage_instance.value`, the easiest way would be to add `value` property method to `Stage` model.

```
class Stage(models.Model):
    stage_number = models.CharField()
    stage_name = models.CharField()
    zones = models.ManyToManyField(Zone, through='ZoneStage')

    @property
    def value(self):
        return ZoneSubStage.objects.filter(substage__stage=self).aggregate(Sum('value')).get('value__sum', 0)
```

Comment: Q1: I do not know how to use stage_value as per your comment. I have just update my model as per update above and as per your advice but it does not work. Q2: I do not want to add the value of Stage itself. Stage value needs to be sum of its SubStages values.

Comment: The command itself should work (I have tested it, and it works as expected). The problem is, that you are trying to do this in `save()`, when `ZoneSubStages` are not connected to the `ZoneStage` yet. You also forgot to define `stage_instance`

Comment: so how should i use it ? should i just add a field as per your comment in my models or should i create a function in my views ? any advice on it please ?

Comment: Just to be clear, I never suggested any new model fields... Given your models, I would update `ZoneStage.value` each time a new `SubStage` is added, since that is when you can actually calculate the value. You can do this in `ZoneSubStage.save()` or you could use [post save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save). You also might want to reevaluate your models - they seem unnecessarily complex. But I might be completely off, based on what your problem is.

Comment: @BlueTomato and if you are asking how to keep everything in sync, that's a different question alltogether. Depending on how quickly and how often the data changes, you might want to drop the field `value` on `ZoneStage` and simply make it a property method instead.

Comment: The data will change once a week only. It will be updated via a form once a week and will save it so I can get a weekly update of the data once a week and always see the previous values from the previous weeks.

Comment: @BlueTomato you basically want to update the value each time it changes on a `ZoneSubStage` or when a `SubStage` is added or removed. If you need more information about this, you might want to post a new question. And please mark this question as answered, if the command works for you - displaying the sum, which is your original question.

Comment: I can not confirm the command works for me at the moment and this is why I have not marked it because I can not say it answers my question. All I want to do it to sum the values and display the sum as described above always and update it if the SubStage value changes or if new SubStage is added.

Comment: @BlueTomato ok, my bad, I didn't understand which part of the original question was missing. I edited the answer and it should work now. (and remove the `save()` method that you added on `ZoneStage`. That is not needed.)

Comment: hi zanderle, for some reasons it returns the total value of substages for a single stage by stage only and I can not filter it by stage by zone...can you help ?

Comment: @BlueTomato I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?